# batch run of shell sript with passing values

Tags: linux, shell, batch-processing

I have a shell script (test.sh) which has some arguments to be passed during execution in linux. For example,

```
# sh test.sh        #My script
Choose model name
0:ESM 1:WED 2:PWD
1                   #I need to choose one from the above
Choose time period
0:2050 1:2080 2:2100
2                   #I need to choose one from the above
Downloading WED data for 2100    #download started
....
```

I am looking for a command to execute the test.sh for the above example. I tried with

`sh test.sh > & out &`

It is terminating without asking me anything.

Comment: `> & out &` what do you think this means?

Comment: I would like to save the details in out file so that I can check any errors later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a way to pass input to a script in a batch-way. Just pipe it:

```
{ echo 1; echo 2; } | sh test.sh
```

Alternatively, I sometimes do it with `printf "%s\n"`, which doesn't need to do `{` `}` braces for multiple lines of input.

```
printf "%s\n" 1 2 "another arg" "etc.." | sh test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the arguments on the command line, and use the variables `$1`,`$2`, etc to use them.

```
./test.sh arg1 arg2 > out
```